# What is data structure used for Elasticsearch flattened type

Tags: elasticsearch, data-structures

I was trying to find how `flattened` type in Elasticsearch works under the hood, the documentation specifies that all leaf values will be indexed into a single field as a keyword, as a result, there will be a dedicated index for all those flattened keywords.

From documentation:

> By default, Elasticsearch indexes all data in every field and each indexed field has a dedicated, optimized data structure. For example, text fields are stored in inverted indices, and numeric and geo fields are stored in BKD trees.

**The specific case that I am trying to understand:**

If I have flattened field and index object with nested objects there is the ability to query a specific nested key in the flattened object. See how to query by `labels.release`:

```
PUT bug_reports
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "labels": {
        "type": "flattened"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST bug_reports/_doc/1
{
  "labels": {
    "priority": "urgent",
    "release": ["v1.2.5", "v1.3.0"]
  }
}
    
POST bug_reports/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {"labels.release": "v1.3.0"}
  }
}
```

Would `flattened` field have the same index structure as the keyword field, and how it is able to reference the specific child key of `flattened` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial design and implementation of the `flattened` field type is described in [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/33003). The leaf keys are also indexed along with the leaf values, which is how they are allowing the search for a specific sub-field.

There are some ongoing [improvements](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/43805) to the `flattened` field type and Elastic would also like to [support numeric values](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/61550), but that's not yet released.